# Windows 10 Update - Close Laptop

Tags: updates

I just started up my laptop at the airport, but I forgot it updated when I shut it down yesterday. Now, at startup, it says “working on updates. Don’t turn off your pc. This will take a while. Your pc will restart several times.” It’s taking a really long time and i’m going to have to shut my laptop soon to board my flight. Will I break my laptop if I shut it during this update?

Comment: Try to wait for a restart and shut it down then, that should not cause any issues.